# How to push new git branch to remote, but keeping the correct parent branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, branch, git-branch

I have the following local git structure:

```
--master--------...
           \---/release---
                          \--/bugfix--
```

So, I have my `master` branch, then `/release` is a branch created from `master` and `/bugfix` a branch created from `release`. The problem I'm having is that after I commit changes in `bugfix`, when I try to do:

```
git push origin -u /bugfix
```

…the branch `bugfix` in the remote gets created from `master` instead of being created from `release`.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. When you push `bugfix`, it will push all commits of this branch (including the ones of release). Once created, branches don't have a "parent branch" (a common misconception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the release branch's origin is pushed and that your hotfix was checkedout from the release branch. Other than that, no such magic should happens.

Also, you should have a development branch before master. From this branch, create your release branch and when ready, merge in master. When merged, merge master back to development branch. HotFix or bugfix can be from your release branch or master, depending on your needs. Take a look at this common git flow

[image]